# How to use netsh to delete a profile with UTF8 characters?

Tags: windows, windows-8, wireless-networking, unicode, netsh

I connected to a W with UTF-8 characters (One of the Doctor Who ones, ┓┏ 凵 =╱⊿┌┬┐ or similar) which clashed terribly with Windows' assumption that UTF-16 is used everywhere.
Now I can't delete it from my network list.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan show profile

Profiles on interface WiFi:

Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
    <None>

User profiles
-------------
    /* Redacted */ 
    All User Profile     : â""â"? å╬µ =â±âS¿â"Oâ"¬â"?
    /* Redacted */ 

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan delete profile name="┓┏ 凵 =╱⊿┌┬┐"
Profile "?? ? =??┌┬┐" is not found on any interface.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan delete profile name="â""â"? å╬µ =â±âS¿â"Oâ"¬â"?"
One or more parameters for the command are not correct or missing.
```

Is it possible to remove it without wiping the other network profiles too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Workaround

You could manually backup all profiles, delete all of them, and finally import everything back. This command will **delete all profiles** (no matter what the profile names are) **by using a wildcard**:

```
netsh wlan delete profile name="*"
```

## Batch automation

The following script will:

1. Export all profiles, automatically skipping those with unsupported characters in their name.
2. Wipe all of them.
3. Import everything saved in step 1.

   ```
   @echo off
   cd /d "%~dp0"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

   set folder="%cd%\Profiles"
   if not exist "%folder%\" md "%folder%"

   for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%G in ('netsh wlan show profile') do (
   set name=%%G
   set name=!name:~1!
   netsh wlan export profile name="!name!" folder="%folder%" >nul
   )

   netsh wlan delete profile name="*"
   echo.
   for /r "%folder%" %%G in (*.xml) do netsh wlan add profile filename="%%G"

   echo. & pause
   exit /b
   ```