# Why does my wifi name show up as <wifi name> <number>?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I'm on a laptop with Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter, Windows 10. I am irritated with the fact that my wifi name has a number, for instance, my wifi name is Arnid and its name comes up as Arnid too but after connecting it shows as Arnid 3, do not confuse this with 5GHz concept, I have a 5GHz wifi too but its name is different, the problem here is how windows names this for some weird reason, Here's screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `netsh wlan show profiles`

Comment: You might have used a USB adapter for WIFI or have changed wifi routers while conserving the same name for the SSID. The answer below should remove the extra SSID in your system's list.

Comment: @YLearn - "WifI' must be a WLAN profile instead of a LAN profile.  I confirmed my commands worked on Windows 10.

Comment: @YLearn - I already know all of that.  In any event, I know what the author was referring to, so clarification isn't required.  The screenshots actually make it clear what the author was referring to.

Comment: @Ramhound, didn't follow the screenshot links, so thanks for editing those in. But the screenshots actually prove the opposite. When you hover over the network icon, you are actually shown the network location/profile name, not the WLAN profile name. I have confirmed this on two different Windows 10 systems.

Comment: @YLearn - So are you saying my answer has the incorrect command?  If that is the case, suggest an edit to the answer, I might consider it.

Comment: @Ramhound, I am not personally well versed in the registry keys that are required to be edited in Win10 to "merge" network profile/locations. There are quite a few posts/guides online for this but I cannot validate the veracity of any of them personally, which is also why I did not provide my own answer. As for your commands, they are correct for displaying and deleting WLAN profiles AFAIK.

Answer (score 9):

Each time I replaced my Wifi hotspot but used the same name as before, Windows recognized it as a new/different hotspot with a name that collided with the old name, so they would throw a "1" or "2", etc. on the end of the ProfileName so that they're unique.  This is what's being described here, and I finally found out how to fix it.

I searched forever for the right answer on this and found it here: https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/125963-my-wi-fi-adapter-displays-wi-fi-2-a.html in post #3 on that page.  I did it, and it worked.  I'll document my steps here as they are slightly different than the ones on that page.  Take a backup or snapshot first since you'll be editing the registry.  If you're not familiar with Regedit, you might want to find someone who is so they can follow these steps for you.  I couldn't find any other way to do this in the GUI of the latest Windows 10.

1. Click the Windows Start button at the lower left of the screen.
2. Type "Regedit" and click "Registry Editor". (it will ask for elevated permissions)
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\`
4. Look in each profile folder (they're unusefully named as GUID's like `{799A828D-382C-4C19-B13D-D22C7CB4E416}`) at the key named "ProfileName" in each profile.
5. You'll see multiple profiles for your WiFi hotspot, each one with a number after it, like "MyHotspot", "MyHotspot 1", "MyHotspot 2", etc. Mine was currently up to "MyHotspot 4", so I deleted the GUID folders that contained ProfileNames of "MyHotspot", "MyHotspot 1", "MyHotspot 2", and "MyHotspot 3", **and I kept** "MyHotspot 4".  I deleted each one by clicking on the GUID folder name on the left and hitting the `DELETE` key.
   [image: Regedit Screenshot]
6. I double-clicked the ProfileName for "MyHotspot 4" and removed the " 4" off the end.
7. I rebooted my PC.  When it came back up, it just showed "MyHotspot"!  Yay!

Comment: In my case the effect is immediate - I don't even have to disconnect and connect again. As soon as I saved the registry change, hovering over the Wi-Fi icon on bottom right showed the new name. (Win10 20H2)

Answer (score 6):

> I am irritated with the fact that my wifi name has a number, for instance, my wifi name is Arnid, and its name comes up as Arnid too but after connecting it shows as Arnid 3

You should run `netsh wlan show profiles` to show every wireless profile on your system.

You can use `netsh wlan delete profile name="Arnid 3"` to delete the unwanted profile.  You should repeat the process and delete any profile that is unwanted.  If you remove all the profiles, then you will have to provide the passphrase to the network once you reconnect[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1257859/remove-an-unused-hidden-network-connection-so-that-an-existing-name-can-be-reuse).

You can use `netsh wlan delete profile name="*"` to delete all of your wireless network profiles[.](https://superuser.com/questions/703558/how-to-use-netsh-to-delete-a-profile-with-utf8-characters/703604#703604)

Comment: I did what you told me to but it still shows “Arnid 3” I deleted all the profiles still it shows Arnid 3, I’ll try a reboot to see if that helps.

Comment: Thats a wrong answer, because it regards Wifi SSID profiles, not Wifi-card profiles.

Comment: @JanvanderZanden - So downvote the answer. I am not sure I am smart enough to understand the difference between “WiFi SSID” profiles and “WiFi Card” profiles. I verified this answer was accurate before I submitted it.