# What is the number behind tethering Wi-Fi name on Windows and how to reset it?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, android, tethering

I often use my Android phone data to access the internet on a PC running Windows 10 by tethering. And I noticed the Wi-Fi has a number behind its name. The number keeps going up every time I turn on the portable hotspot and connect my PC to it.

What is that number and how to reset it back to 0 or 1?

Comment: Are you using Windows? Note that I've also observed this on Windows 10.

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, I'm using Windows 10 Home Edition

Comment: I have a feeling that this is actually a Windows' quirk since it doesn't happen on other OS (e.g. macOS), and possibly not really related to Android. The community on our sister site for general software/OS [su] may have more knowledge about this issue than the Android community here. I can migrate the question to there if you want.

Comment: @AndrewT. sorry for late reply. I'm fine with the question migration to more appropriate community since I'm not sure if this is an issue from Windows or Android. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Does the increasing number break anything? If not, ignore it and carry on. If yes, see what [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) is and state the real issue (what gets broken? [edit] the question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my wifi name show up as <wifi name> <number>?](https://superuser.com/questions/1520024/why-does-my-wifi-name-show-up-as-wifi-name-number)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no problem occurred  so far. I just want to know the meaning behind those number, and why it only happen with phone tethering hotspot and not with wi-fi from router.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thank you, it answer my question how to reset the number but still doesn't answer the meaning behind those number.

Comment: Usually the number is incremented by 1. No real meaning. If when you previously connected the SSID was Something 1, the next time you connect, it will Something2.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I see, thanks for the answer and help